# как записать информацию из цикла в файл

Tags: python, python-2.x

Есть код:

```
import wmi
c = wmi.WMI ()
for disk in c.Win32_LogicalDisk (DriveType=3):
    print disk.Caption,long (disk.Size),long (disk.FreeSpace)`
```

который выводит (кортеж, если я не ошибаюсь) примерно следующее -

```
C: 209610338304 34677112832
D: 290390536192 6689439744
```

я хочу записать эту информацию в файл txt.
у меня получился вот такой код

```
import wmi
c = wmi.WMI ()
values = []
for disk in c.Win32_LogicalDisk (DriveType=3):
values.append(u'{}   {}'.format(disk.Caption,long(disk.Size),long(disk.FreeSpace)))
f = open ('file name.txt', 'w')
for value in values:
   f.write(value + '\n')
f.close
```

записывает только вот это -

```
C: 209610338304 
D: 290390536192
```

т.е. все кроме остатка свободного места на диске . 
не знаю как решить данную проблему ..

Comment: И в чем, собственно, проблема? Формируйте строку и пишите ее в файл. Или пишите данные сразу в файл.

Comment: Игорь, а вы умеете вообще писать в файл в python? Если нет, может об этом и надо спрашивать тогда?

Comment: @Владимир Мартьянов, по идеи функция принт выводит кортеж если я не ошибаюсь . я перепробовал множество вариантов. максимум чего я добился это записывает название диска с размер диска а сколько свободного места не записывает и хоть ты что делай ... если не трудно можно ваш вариант записи ... заранее спасибо!!!

Comment: Нельзя, потому что у меня его нет.

Comment: @Nick Volynkin вроде как умею. и в конце концов в интернете полно примеров и что бы не посмотреть это надо быть совсем ленивым .

Comment: @Игорь тогда совсем непонятно, в чем проблема. Читаю свежие комментарии - вроде стало яснее.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов хорошо ... тогда может сделаем так - 
`import wmi
c = wmi.WMI ()
values = []
for disk in c.Win32_LogicalDisk (DriveType=3):
  values.append(u'{} {}'.format(disk.Caption,long(disk.Size),long(disk.FreeSpace)))
f = open ('file name.txt', 'w')
for value in values:
   f.write(value + '\n')
f.close`
что не так ?

Comment: @Nick Volynkin я бы в комментарии писал бы все мои  комбинации написания но тут ругаются вроде как если много кода записываешь в комментарии .

Comment: @Игорь а вы можете код добавлять в сам вопрос, используйте кнопку [edit]

Comment: Впрочем, вы уже ведь умеете.

Comment: @Nick Volynkin вот взгляните .

Answer (score 1):

```
import wmi
c = wmi.WMI ()
values = []
for disk in c.Win32_LogicalDisk (DriveType=3):
  values.append(u'{} {} {}'.format(disk.Caption,long(disk.FreeSpace),long(disk.Size)))
f = open ('file name.txt', 'w')
for value in values:
   f.write(value + '\n')
f.close
```

не хватало третьей {}